# Background-Image Slideshow in Js (& HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, slideshow

I'm trying to implement a simple background image slideshow on my website but I can't find a good tutorial on the internet so I thought I'd ask here.

HTML:

```html
<body>
   <h3>Welcome!</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
```

JS:

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var slideTime = 3000; // 3 seconds

images[0] = '/img/bg1.jpg';
images[1] = '/img/bg2.jpg';
images[2] = '/img/bg3.jpg';

function changePicture() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = images[i];

    if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("changePicture()", slideTime);
}

window.onload = changePicture;
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("img/bg2.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Is your code working? Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background image requires URL to wrap the image file when passing an image file.

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var slideTime = 3000; // 3 seconds

images[0] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/300AAA';
images[1] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/000300';
images[2] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/AAA300';

function changePicture() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";

    if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(changePicture, slideTime);
}

window.onload = changePicture;
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150/300AAA");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<h3>Welcome!</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :) Somehow only pictures with direct-links work, not local saved ones.

Comment: DavidB, for using locally saved images with the method above, try hosting the webpage on your localhost in a test server. This worked for me